# Camera stuck in my character

Tags: workflow

I have a character and i'm doing a rigging / skinning.  I don't know how it happened, but my view is now stuck in my Character.  I can't get out of it, either with my mouse or any View option.  I do have a camera in my scene and the problem is not related with it...

You can see the .blend file here:  http://dropcanvas.com/h5o5k

thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 2):

You have locked your camera to the character. Press <kbd>N</kbd> to open the *properties shelf*. Go to *View* panel and delete the name of the object under the *Lock to Object* header.
[image]

Answer (score -1):

An easier way is to try clicking on the number pad. if that does not work, try exiting blender and going back in..

Comment: If the camera is locked to the object that will be saved in the .blend file hence exiting won't really help.